Error from Google Cloud Run - Deploying containers
I am getting this error when I am trying to deploy a simple python container in Google Cloud Run:
Revision 'flask-backend-00001-vxb' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. Cloud Run does not support image 'us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/indigo-replica-446423-m6/flask-backend/flask_backend': Container manifest type 'application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json' must support amd64/linux.


So the issue is I was building the container on an M mac which runs on ARM and defaults to building containers that are optimized for ARM where as Google Cloud Run runs container on linux/amd64.
You need to specify the platform you want to build them on:
Build your container using this command:
docker buildx build -t flask_backend:latest --platform linux/amd64 .
